# Creating categories with rows information with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time, xlsx

I'm using a database (xlsx) that's informs the time that the animals were inside of the studied area, like this:

[image: Data]

I wanna separate the hours in groups, pick up the time and put it in categories.

24h-6h - Dawn
6h-12h - Morning
12h-18h - Afternoon
18h - 24h - Night

So instead of "21:25:00" would be "night", "10:36:00" would be "morning" and so on.

How can i do it with pandas? I tried to use the same method used to rename the columns, something like this.

`pamdf.loc[pamdf['Hora em que foram detectados dentro da área de exclusão'].isin( ['24:00:00':'06:00:00' ]), 'Hora em que foram detectados dentro da área de exclusão'] = 'Dawn'`

But it didn't make any sense and obviously didn't work. Can i use "pandas.cut"? how?

Thanks in advance folks and sorry for the bad english.

EXAMPLE:

```
Hour  
21:25
10:36
23:17
04:55
21:12
23:58
19:55
20:54
23:01
00:20
18:54
```

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you provide some data and a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

def convert_to_category(x):
    if x in set([i for i in range(1,7)]):
        return 'Dawn'
    elif x in set([i for i in range(7,13)]):
        return 'Morning'
    elif x in set([i for i in range(13,19)]):
        return 'Afternoon'
    else:
        return 'Night'

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['21:25:00','10:36:00','23:17:00']})

df['period'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.hour.apply(lambda x: convert_to_category(x))


    time        period
0   21:25:00    Night
1   10:36:00    Morning
2   23:17:00    Night
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i didn't knew how to apply the lambda on that situation